# Hokuyo - No map received in RViz

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am trying to use the package "GMapping" to visualize the map acquired with Hokuyo laser scanner!

I have no odometry, so I simulated a TF with a launch file, which worked already in other applications!

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="US6" args="0 7 2 1.5708 0 0 base_link laser 100" />

</launch>
```

When running RViz, in Global Options, the Fixed frame is map;
In Grid, the Reference Frame is map;
In TF I have the following warnings: No transform from [map] to [base_link] / No transform from [odom] to [base_link]
In map, the topic is map and I receive this warning and error message: No map received / No transform from [] to [base_link]

What did I do wrong? I notice that if I change the Fixed Frame in Global Options and the one in Grid, the error disappear and some other errors appear... what are the correct options to be selected in Global Options and in Grid?

Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191491/hokuyo---no-map-received-in-rviz/) by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As bvbdort already mentioned, you need to also publish the base_link -> odom transform. If you don't have an odometry system, you can do it with a static transform publisher in your launch file like this:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="US6" args="0 7 2 1.5708 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
</launch>
```

That way every transform gmapping expects to run is set up.
Mind that gmapping won't really be able to extimate the position of the laser in the map, since you publish odometry information manually as a static transformation. But at least you should see a map built from your laser.

PS: If it still doesn't work that way, please provide info about what gmapping prints out.

---

Originally posted by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) with karma: 136 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-09-02**:
Thank you Malefitz, it works =) now I have another question but i'll open a new one, since it isn't related with the transforms!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Required_tf_Transforms) you also need transform between baselink and odom

**Required tf Transforms**

```
<the frame attached to incoming scans> → base_link
```

usually a fixed value, broadcast periodically by a robot_state_publisher, or a tf static_transform_publisher.

```
base_link → odom
```

usually provided by the odometry system (e.g., the driver for the mobile base)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-31**:
@bvbdort Since I don't have odometry, the second transform was the one I "simulated".

For the first one, does this exact transform in the tf static_transform_publisher ros page solves? (next comment)

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-31**:

what do I write in link1_broadcaster, link1_parent and link1?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-31**:
base_link --> odom is not static you cant simulate this from static_transform_publisher.

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-31**:
But isn't that the one I already simulate?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-31**:
static_transform_publisher  you showed in question is between laser and base link

**Comment by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) on 2014-09-02**:
For testing purposes it is ok to publish the odometry with a static publisher. I'll write an answer for it.

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-09-02**:
Thank you @Malefitz, really appreciate it!